# powershell: can I string together unrelated cmdlets?

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have powershell script that works, but I'd like to see if there is a better way to accomplish this task.

Right now I am using several different if statements followed by script blocks containing one cmdlet each.  Is there a way to put these cmdlets all within the curly braces?

I've tried piping but the cmdlets don't need input from the prior cmdlet.

```
$Filepath1 = 'h:\test_network\book1.csv'
$Filepath2 = 'c:\test_local\book2.csv'

$hashes = 
foreach ($Filepath in $Filepath1,$Filepath2)
{
 $MD5 = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create( "MD5" )
 $stream = ([IO.StreamReader]"$Filepath").BaseStream
 -join ($MD5.ComputeHash($stream) | 
 ForEach { "{0:x2}" -f $_ })
 $stream.Close()
 }

if ($hashes[0] -eq $hashes[1])
        {write-host 'Files Match' -foregroundcolor green}

if  ($hashes[0] -eq $hashes[1])
        {copy-item $filepath2 c:\test_archive\}

if ($hashes[0] -eq $hashes[1])
        {remove-item $filepath2}

if  ($hashes[0] -ne $hashes[1])
        {write-host 'Files do not match' -foregroundcolor red}  

if  ($hashes[0] -ne $hashes[1])
        {remove-item $filepath2}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement should work in PowerShell:

```
if ($hashes[0] -eq $hashes[1])
{
    write-host 'Files Match' -foregroundcolor green
    copy-item $filepath2 c:\test_archive\
    remove-item $filepath2
}
else
{
    write-host 'Files do not match' -foregroundcolor red
    remove-item $filepath2
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see where I was making my mistake when I tried to consolidate:  I was putting write-host copy-item remove-item etc. on same line.   I did not realize that cmdlets needed to be on separate lines.

Comment: They don't if you finish them with a ;

Comment: Wow!  somehow I missed that in the text I was using.  Thanks for the quick answers!